# List/Array of dates to be used by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, arrays, razor, webmatrix

I'm after some guidance. I have a SQL select statement which pulls a bunch of dates out of my database. I then need to put them into an array or list (i'm not sure which would be best) so that it can be consumed by a jquery script (which will show these dates on a calendar).

My SQL select statement looks like this:

```
var getBooked = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Property_Availability WHERE PropertyID = @0", rPropertyId);
```

How do i add these to an array. using a foreach loop?

Comment: A `List<T>` will be fine, it will serialize to JSON as an array for you to consume client side. Yes, probably use a loop to populate the list or try `ToList()` on your query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for dates only then this is what you need to select

```
var getBooked = 
db.Query("SELECT myDate FROM Property_Availability WHERE PropertyID = @0"
, rPropertyId).LoList();
```

This returns a list of dates. I'm adding sample on how to call your method and get and process this list from client

```
function getDates() {
 var myDates= [];
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "yourPage/yourMethod",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {
         var dates= response.d;
         $.map(dates, function (item) 
             myArray.push(item);
         });
         alert("success");
     },
     failure: function (msg) {
         alert("fail");
     }
});
return myDates;
```

}

as a result of this function you getting client side array representing your server list

Comment: and will my list be called "getBooked"?

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean - your var getBooked will be a list with your dates.

Comment: @foreach(string date in getBooked){
                            <p>@date</p>
                        }

Comment: The above isn't working when i'm trying to iterate through that list?

Comment: Are you getting back results from your query? Does your getBooked contains any items?